# curl command in Unix giving exception

Tags: curl

I am executing the below curl command and getting the error:

```
curl -Method Post -Header @{'Content-Type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}-Body @{grant_type = 'password';username = 'abcd';password = 'xyz'} "http://someaddress/api/oauth/token" -O test_curl
```

Could you please check what wrong I am doing here?

Error:

```
Warning: built-in manual was disabled at build-time!
curl: option -Method: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
```

Comment: Did… did you just make up those options?! And what’s that `@{…}` syntax? Something’s really strange here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Method` option should be `-X` or `--request`. The `-Header` option should be `-H` or `--header`.  Also, you must use double quotes to pass the JSON header with single quotes to `curl`.

Try this:

```
curl -XPOST -H "@{'Content-Type'='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}-Body @{grant_type = 'password';username = 'abcd';password = 'xyz'}" -o test_curl "http://someaddress/api/oauth/token"
```

Comment: i never used curl so dont know if there is a separate curl console to run the command. I tried this command and getting the error.                                                             curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'test_curl'

Comment: Edited a typo. Try again.

Comment: now getting only one error : curl: (7) couldn't connect to host.  i am running it from /home/username and test_curl is created in this path .

Comment: Which host are you using? Do not use `someaddress` as in the example.

Comment: no that is dummy one .. i am using the correct one.

Comment: Then it's another network related problem. Check your DNS, /etc/hosts, connectivity, etc.

Comment: i checked in other server ..it is working now.  Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184032/discussion-between-ricardo-branco-and-kashi).